# The keyword 'private' is reserved (35:12) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-2017, angular5

I am getting a strange issue now on my Angular 5 application. The error stack is given below.

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/app/registration/registration.component.ts Module parse failed:
>   The keyword 'private' is reserved (35:12) You may need an appropriate
>   loader to handle this file type. |     }; | } | constructor(private,
>   fb, FormBuilder); | { |     this.form = fb.group({  @
>   ./src/app/app.module.ts 16:0-78  @ ./src/main.ts  @ multi
>   webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts

Here is my code.

```
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  form;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, isEmailValid('email')]],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
    }, { validator: compareValidator('password', 'confirmPassword') });
  }

  function compareValidator(control1, control2) {
    return form => {
      if (form.controls[control1].value !== form.controls[control2].value) {
        return { compareResult: true };
      }
    }
  }

  function isEmailValid(control) {
    return control => {
      var regex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
      return regex.test(control.value) ? null : { invalidEmail: true };
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Can anyone please help me to find what is the issue? By any chance, if you need to see my package versions, I am attaching my **package.json** file.

```
{
  "name": "my-angular5-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.5",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.92",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes a small issue can make you scratch your head, this one was such kind. I don't know why I had done such a small mistake. Just removing the two functions outside of the class solved the issue. Just sharing it with the other folks who might have ended up in the same situation.

```
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  form;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, isEmailValid('email')]],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
    }, { validator: compareValidator('password', 'confirmPassword') });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

function compareValidator(control1, control2) {
  return form => {
    if (form.controls[control1].value !== form.controls[control2].value) {
      return { compareResult: true };
    }
  }
}

function isEmailValid(control) {
  return control => {
    var regex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
    return regex.test(control.value) ? null : { invalidEmail: true };
  }
}
```

If you remove the keyword "function" and use define your function inside the class, you will get an error as *isEmailValid is undefined*.

Comment: this didnt help me.  Maybe a further investigation needs to be done.  An error occured when i removed my function outside the class.